# Javascript: fast way to check if form contents have been changed before submission

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit

Simple question (I guess)...
I'm in an "edit-some-element" html form.
As the page load, the form is filled with current element attributes (eg. name, etc.)
I could modify some input fields or even decide not to do that but I click the same on submit button because is the only available one.

MY QUESTION:
is there a property/attribute of the input elements containig the initial input values that I can access to compare them with the current ones when I click on submit button?
In other words:
is there a fast way to check if at least one input field has been changed before submitting the form? (so to stop the event if an update isn't really necessary)
(and I mean "really changed" not considering as changes when I modify something but rewrite it as it was before)

I'd like a minimal example:
How to check if a simple input-text "name" has been changed

P.S.
Of course, to trigger the "check-if-something-changed" function,
if I decide to use pure javascript I would use onSubmit event while using jQuery I would use something like:

```
$('#formMod').submit(function(){ ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering if is it possible using jQuery to achieve the check on input changes in a way like this: `if($('input[DefaultValue!=input.value]').lenght==0){...}` what about it? (the example i wrote didn't seems to work but i neither get error-notices using it...)

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370388/jquery-selector-comparing-two-elements-attributes-between-them) answers my second question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the input element [`defaultValue`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_defaultvalue.asp) dom property:

```
function validateInput(input) {
    if (input.value == input.defaultValue) {
        alert("Please change field.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't know that defaultValue existed!

Comment: Me neither... Simple yet deadly, GREAT! Now I think the best thing to do is call a function containing a loop on all input fields to check for changes and, if something changed, go on with form validation/submission; otherwise stop the event, no need to continue. THANK YOU MAN!