# jQuery selector comparing element's attributes (and/or properties) between them

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes, properties, comparison

The thing starts from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369683/javascript-fast-way-to-check-if-form-contents-have-been-changed-before-submissi):
Using jQuery is it possible to compare two attributes in a selector?
I mean something like:

```
$('element[atribute1!=attribute2]')
```

or, in a practical example:

```
$('input[name!=id]')
```

In my case, I would need it to get how many input fields haven't been changed in an html form used to edit something,
I was trying to get this code to work:

```
if($('input[DefaultValue!=input.value]').lenght==0){...}
```

What about it?
It should return the number of changed fields (if i get 0 i will stop form submission, show an alert message and go back without updating)

Thank for your help.

Comment: Just curious.. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes... the code doesn't seem to work right (the form submission go on) but I don't get error notices (using firefox 8 + webdeveloper plugin)

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment so PLEASE REGRET: I don't only mispelled the word "length" at first but then I even CHEERED TOO SOON, 'CAUSE MY CODE IS STILL WRONG FOR WHAT I INTENTED TO ACHIEVE (now I always get as if the number of modified elements is equal to 0). Thank you RightSaidFred, will try your code.

Comment: (I removed my comment in which I wrote the code was working so to avoid someone reading it to be confused)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If you look through jQuery's documentation, you'll see there's no such selector.

Also `defaultValue` is a property, not an attribute.

You can do this:

```
var changed = $('input').filter(function() {
    return this.value !== this.defaultValue;
});
```

Comment: Hello there RightSaidFred... Thank for your reply. Yes, it's true me neither found anything about that way to use jQuery... it seemed to work but I realized I always get the message "you didn't modified data" so I'm going to edit my previous comment. Thank you.

Comment: your code worked very nice, thank you!

I just have a last question: if I change this line

`var changed = $('input[name^="modcc_"]').filter(function() {`

to this

`var changed = $('input[name^="modcc_"]', myForm).filter(function() {`

I always get as if I didn't change anything... I know for sure that myForm is the string "#formMod" (same as the id of my form that is id="formMod")

Comment: @danicotra: Not sure why that would be. You're sure that these inputs are inside `formMod`? Do you have more than one element with that same ID?

Comment: Hey hello! I accepted your as answer to my question and just made [another question about this specific issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374672/is-it-possible-to-mix-multiple-selector-and-filter-using-jquery). Anyway: yes I am sure the inputs are inside that form and that it's the only thing with that ID

Comment: @danicotra: I answered your other question. It became clear once you showed your HTML markup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jQuery filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function, like this:

```
var different = $('input').filter(function()
{
    return $(this).attr('data-default-value') != $(this).val();   
});
```

Then, you can test `different.length > 0`.

Here's a full working example: http://jsfiddle.net/us47d/

Comment: Your code doesn't seems to work, I always get as if I changed all my form input fields!

Comment: My jsfiddle example works fine. If your implementation differs, post your source code.

Comment: I understood... the fact is I didn't put the data-default-value attribute to my inputs... Some questions for you: 1 is it a "standard" html/xhtml attribute? (never knew about it) 2 I think I'll go rightsaidfred way (otherwise I should retouch all my input fields...), do you think are there many advantages using yours instead? ...and 3, please could you reply my last comment on rightsaidfred answer? Thanks.

Comment: When making up your own custom attributes, the HTML specs prefer to name them like `data-library-name`, so a attribute like `data-default-value` will validate. However, I was not aware that there already existed a HTML attribute for inputs called `defaultValue` (see specs [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6043025)), so I would actually use `defaultValue` instead.

Comment: Ok wsanville, many thanks... I'm still waiting for an answer to the question I made with my last comment on RightSaidFred answer, maybe I will create a new answer... Bye, thank you again.