# Is it possible to mix multiple selector and filter using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, filter, attributes

I know there's the possibility, using jQuery, to [mix Multiple Selector with Multiple Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/#comment-31529105) and, indeed, I used it.
For example, this works fine:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name^="selected"]:checked', theForm).length
```

In my example, "theForm" is a string containing "#form1" which I use to refer to my form that has the attribute id="form1".

Well, that said, the question is: is it possible mixing the above with jQuery filter?
Here is a code example:

```
var myVar = $('input[name^="modcc_"]', myForm).filter(...)
```

I tried to use this and I seem not to get elements in myVar
 but If I simply remove "myForm" this way

```
var myVar = $('input[name^="modcc_"]').filter(...)
```

it works ... WHY? Am I doing something wrong? I know for sure that "myForm" variable is correctly "stuffed" (it's a string containing "#formMod" which coincide to my form's id attribute) and I am sure the inputs are inside that form and that it's the only thing with that ID.

Thank for your help!

P.S.
This question comes from [one of my previous I made in a comment to the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370388/jquery-selector-comparing-elements-attributes-and-or-properties-between-them) that didn't get answered. I thought it could anyway deserved to be made as a question instead of a simple comment so... here it is! Hope to have an answer to it...

-Edit
as asked, I put here the form HTML code:

```
<form action="..." method="post" id="formMod" name="formMod">
   <input type="hidden" name="catid" value="412" />
   <td width="8%">412</td>
   <td>myName</td>
   <td width="9%" style="white-space:nowrap; background-color:LightGoldenRodYellow;">
       <input id="modcc_icv" name="modcc_icv" type="text" value="10" maxlength="3" size="4" />.
       <input id="modcc_dcv" name="modcc_dcv" type="text" value="25" maxlength="2" size="3" />%
   </td>
   <td width="18%" class="actions_col" style="background-color:LightGoldenRodYellow;">
       [ <a href="...">Annnulla</a> ] 
       <input type="submit" name="confirmMod" value="Salva" />
   </td>
</form>
```

Comment: Would something like this help? $("#letters option").filter("[attr=a],[attr=b]").remove().  or you can try the .add() class http://api.jquery.com/add/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using invalid markup.

You can't have a `<form>` element as the direct child of a `<tr>` element.

Your HTML will be reworked in various ways depending on the browser, and the `<td>` elements and their content will likely be removed from the `form` so that the `<td>`s are the children of the `<tr>`.

When I put your markup in Chrome, this is how it is rendered:

```
<tr>
      <!-- THE FORM HAS LOST ITS CONTENT -->
   <form action="..." method="post" id="formMod" name="formMod"></form>

   <input type="hidden" name="catid" value="412">
   <td width="8%">412</td>
   <td>myName</td>
   <td width="9%" style="white-space:nowrap; background-color:LightGoldenRodYellow;">
       <input id="modcc_icv" name="modcc_icv" type="text" value="10" maxlength="3" size="4">.
       <input id="modcc_dcv" name="modcc_dcv" type="text" value="25" maxlength="2" size="3">%
   </td>
   <td width="18%" class="actions_col" style="background-color:LightGoldenRodYellow;">
       [ <a href="...">Annnulla</a> ] 
       <input type="submit" name="confirmMod" value="Salva">
   </td>

</tr>
```

Notice that the `<form>` element is now empty.

So that's why you're able to find the `<input>` elements doing a document wide search, but not from the context of the form itself.

So it has nothing to do with the `.filter()`, but rather with the fact that you're not selecting any elements in the first place.

Comment: @danicotra: One other option would be to not use `<form>` tags at all, and just submit the input data using `$.post()`. But of course this will only work with JavaScript enabled.

Comment: (I use firefox and I see correct page source thus...) I feared that! I knew it was invalid xhtml markup, for example, but the form submission works afterall... Although hoped the cause could be another one, not this, 'cause I can't make the form to contain the entire table by now since every table row can contain other editable contents or actions (i.e. other submittable form) such as delete row/entry command.

Comment: Yeah, I'd avoid rely on $.post() If I can't manage to rewrite my html making my forms to contain entire tables without nested forms, etc. I'm lucky I can still manage to achieve my needs by using enough different names for my form inputs so to avoid to select wrong ones (nevertheless I like my pages to validate correctly so I'll do my best to make them)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're not incorrectly using `myForm` instead of `theForm`?

That being said, what you're doing with the `$(foo,bar)` selector syntax is selecting `foo` elements within a `bar` context. If setting `myForm` as the context does not yield you results (when selecting without it does), that normally just means that you're either selecting in the wrong context, or that there just aren't any elements matching your selector in the given context.

Here's [some more reading about it](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context).

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the name and the content of that variable are right... I too thought it could be my input weren't catch because they were somewhat outside the form ...but they aren't!